# Tutorials on packaging a Java application

Tags: java, build-process, packaging

What are some tutorials and best practices that show to make a build from source code for a Java desktop / Java EE web application?

I want to learn what needs to be packaged as a [WAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29)/[JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) from source and how it must be structured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- JAR: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html
- WAR: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/WCC3.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org):

- [maven war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)
- jars are created simply by issuing `mvn package`

If you're not using Maven at this point - you should seriously consider it. It will relieve you of a lot of build, packaging and dependency management task.

Comment: i am not familar with maven...but i am considering to start learning it. thank you for the commenting.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few links to get started:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(Sun_file_format)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

See the external links section for more detailed information.

EDIT: Sorry the links are broken you need to add the closing ')' at the end.

Comment: umm..i don't see the external links sections in there?